# How to use the DeployIt's namePattern parameter in the repository/query web-service

Tags: deployit

I’m trying to use the REST API provided by DeployIt (v3.9) to list all the packages available on a given project.
Thus, I use the [`GET /repository/query service`](http://docs.xebialabs.com/releases/3.9/deployit/rest-api/com.xebialabs.deployit.engine.api.RepositoryService.html#/repository/query%3aGET)

So, I’m calling this service with the following URL:

```
http://[server]/deployit/repository/query?namePattern=my-app&type=udm.DeploymentPackage
```

Unfortunately, I don’t get anything (just an empty list).

If I remove the `namePattern` from my URL, then I get a long list of all applications (not only the only I'm interested in).
So it appears that I don’t set correctly the `namePattern` attribute. In the documentation, they say:

> a search pattern for the name. This is like the SQL "LIKE" pattern:
>   the character '%' represents any string of zero or more characters,
>   and the character '_' (underscore) represents any single character.
>   Any literal use of these two characters must be escaped with a
>   backslash ('\'). Consequently, any literal instance of a backslash
>   must also be escaped, resulting in a double backslash ('\').

So I tried the following URL:

- http://[server]/deployit/repository/query?type=udm.DeploymentPackage&namePattern=my-app : empty list
- http://[server]/deployit/repository/query?type=udm.DeploymentPackage&namePattern=%my-app%: error 400
- http://[server]/deployit/repository/query?type=udm.DeploymentPackage&namePattern=%25my-app%25 (trying to escape the % character): empty list
- http://[server]/deployit/repository/query?type=udm.DeploymentPackage&namePattern=Applications/my-app/2.0.0 (with a real version): error, character ‘/’ not allowed.
- http://[server]/deployit/repository/query?type=udm.DeploymentPackage&namePattern=2.0.0 : I get the list of all applications deployed with a version `2.0.0` (including my `my-app`), but that's not what I'm looking for (I want *all* versions available on DeployIt for `my-app`).

So, what is the correct URL to retrieve the list of deployed applications?

Answer (score 2):

I've solved my problem. In fact, the `namePattern` only applies to the last part of the Application name, i.e. the version.
Thus, I have to use the `parent` attribute to retrieve the list of my application:

```
http://[server]/deployit/repository/query?type=udm.DeploymentPackage&parent=Applications%2Fmy-app&resultsPerPage=-1
```